# How to write test cases using Equivalence Partitioning(EP) if condition has no range?

Tags: testing, module, equivalent

I have a question regarding test cases using EP strategy. I was assigned to write test cases about water supply company by using water tariff tables given below.

[This is the test cases given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeIKi.png)

I have to write solution using the table format TYPE, EQUIVALENCE CLASS, STATUS, BVA & EXPECTED RESULT.

But one thing i dont understand is how to do it when condition given doesnt have range? This is rate so is it supposed to have invalid status? Can anyone help me with this & provide me the answers? Thank you.